# 2 classes referenced in kivy returns empty screen

Tags: python, kivy

As proposed in my last thread I ask the question because the problem changed. I now have the python code before the builder and now I does show a blank screen in the color of wordApp

I use 2 classes defined in one python file. I want to reference them inside the builder.load_string so that their contents are shown in the respective  Screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am close to the finish of my project.

```
class Word(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.textlabel = Label(text="labeltext", pos=(300, 300))
        self.add_widget(self.textlabel)

    def gonext(self ,btn_inst):
        sm.current = "settings"

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Favorites(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))
sm.add_widget(Favorites(name='favs'))

class WordApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,0,0.3,1)
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WordApp().run()


class WordFile(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.textlabeldef = Label(text="labeltextdef", pos=(300, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.textlabeldef)


class WordFileApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0,1,0.3,1)
        return sm

 Builder.load_string("""
 #:kivy 1.9.0


<MenuScreen>:
    Word:
        Button:
            text: 'change word'
            font_size: 30
            width: root.width
            center_x: 400
            center_y: root.width / 2


<SettingsScreen>:
    WordFile:
        Label:
            width: root.width
            height: 30
            top: root.height 
            id: entry
            text:"ac"
            font_size:18
            multiline:True
            center_x: root.width/2
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

<Favorites>:
    Word:     
""")
```

Comment: please remove redundant lines, and if possible try to make it a little more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of error in your code:

```
class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

- This does nothing
- You declare some classes you use, *after* the start of the App
- You created and build *two* Apps
- There is no `WordFile` rule in the kv part, although you use it
- Some classes had a wrong `__init__`
- Maybe more, that I forgot :o)

This is some code that runs:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


Builder.load_string("""
 #:kivy 1.9.0


<MenuScreen>:
    Word:
        Button:
            text: 'change word'
            font_size: 30
            width: root.width
            center_x: 400
            center_y: root.width / 2


<SettingsScreen>:
    WordFile:
        Label:
            width: root.width
            height: 30
            top: root.height 
            id: entry
            text:"ac"
            font_size:18
            multiline:True
            center_x: root.width/2
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

<Favorites>:
    Word:

<WordFile>:

""")


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Favorites(Screen):
    pass


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Word(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Word, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.textlabel = Label(text="labeltext", pos=(300, 300))
        self.add_widget(self.textlabel)

    def gonext(self, btn_inst):
        sm.current = "settings"


class WordFile(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WordFile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.textlabeldef = Label(text="labeltextdef", pos=(300, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.textlabeldef)


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))
sm.add_widget(Favorites(name='favs'))


class WordApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 0, 0.3, 1)
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WordApp().run()
```

Comment: thank you so much. I do python only for 2 weeks and I try hard to improve my code. Your hints will be used to improve. What do you mean by:                          You declare some classes you use, after the start of the App?

Comment: @NickHallas Since the python script is read from top to bottom, when it reaches the `if __name__` position, it starts the app before the declarations of the last classes.